# BackboneJS view updates

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I have been [reading](http://pragmatic-backbone.com/views) about how to correctly update views in Backbone.js by calling the render function when the data in the model changes and not by using lots of JQuery updates etc. This stops state and data being stored in the view and also spaghetti code later on.

My question is, is this a strict rule? I can imagine situations where re-rendering an entire view to show an error message next to a field is overkill, especially as it's not modifying state or data. What is the suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is no **one** [*recommended*](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-tim-toady) approach for everything, it depends on the specific situation. Especially for more complex views you might want to listen to specific events on the model and update/refresh just part of your view, (for example `this.$('.myTextFieldCnt').addClass('invalid');`.

If you find that you are doing a lot of these *refreshes* you might want to take a look at [Backbone.stickit](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/) which is a backbone plug in that adds data binding to Backbone that can make a lot of these kind updates a bit cleaner (and helps you avoid some that spaghetti code).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's the lack of recommendations with Backbone which make it easy to fall in to bad habits with it.